# Move records from an array of records if matched id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6.

**My dirty code**

```
      active_card_ids = JSON.parse(cookies[:card_ids])
      @active_cards = []

      @best_cards = Houses.where("#{payment_category} IS NOT NULL").order("#{payment_category} DESC")
      @best_cards.each do |card|
        if active_card_ids.include? card.id
          @active_cards << card
        end
      end
```

**What I am trying to do**

I have an array of records queried: `queried_records = [<object id: 1>, <object id: 3>, <object id: 4>, <object id: 7>]`

Another array of IDs: `wanted_ids = [4, 5]`

Create another array: `selected_records = []`

I want to move `queried_records` found in `wanted_ids`, to `selected_records`.

In this example, we found `<object id: 4>` from `queried_records`, so we want to move (not copy) it to `selected_records`.

The results should be `selected_records` return an array `[<object id: 4>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, there will be id's in `active_card_ids` and you want another array with those id's only.

You can try querying the DB directly, then you don't have to run the loop.

The below sample takes an array of id's and passes it to where IN clause to query only active cards.

```
active_card_ids = JSON.parse(cookies[:card_ids])
@active_cards = Houses.where(id: active_card_ids).where("#{payment_category} IS NOT NULL").order("#{payment_category} DESC")
@best_cards = Houses.where("#{payment_category} IS NOT NULL").order("#{payment_category} DESC")
```

Another approach you can try is:

```
active_card_ids = JSON.parse(cookies[:card_ids])
@best_cards = Houses.where("#{payment_category} IS NOT NULL").order("#{payment_category} DESC")
@active_cards = @best_cards.select{ |card| active_card_ids.include? card.id }
```

Comment: Thanks, but making two queries is not what I want. The solution could be done in one query, and select record from that results.